# Clash of Clans restart that can't be fixed

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have been playing EO clash for a while. When I tried to go back the main game, it says "DOWNLOADING EO CLASH UPDATE". I've tried waiting to download the update, but it keeps restarting the game. How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

1. Check you are connected to the internet
2. Restart your device
3. Leave it on downloading it for a bit, forget about it and come back later
4. Restart your internet connection
5. Wait until the next update and contact the support for the game
6. Reinstall the game itself

Go through each step until it fixes, If it still has not then sorry, but I have no more ideas.

Answer (score -1):

You need to download the latest update from your app store.

There was an issue in a past update which was preventing the forced update. Manually downloading the new version from the app store will fix it. 100%.